# Better code layout in Python to comply with PEP 8 character limit

Tags: python, pep8

after my code is finished, I'm trying to improve the readability.

Can you help me to improve the readability of the following lines according to PEP 8 regarding the 80 character limit?

You see, the part == 'Geburtsdatum' is behind the border.

```
def function(x, y):      
    try:
        ...
        
        # Iterate over each row anch check if we use it in our file
        for i in range((dfs[0].shape[0])): 

            if str(dfs[0].at[dfs[0].index[i],dfs[0].columns[0]]).replace(':', '') == 'Geburtsdatum':
                df.at[df.index[0],df.columns[3]] = dfs[0].at[dfs[0].index[i],dfs[0].columns[1]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You could make your own function that will perform the string conversion, replacing and checking, taking in `dfs[0].at[dfs[0].index[i],dfs[0].columns[0]]` and `Geburtsdam` (and the other values) ; it should save you some characters.
2. You could assign `dfs[0].columns` to a variable `cols` and `dfs[0].index` to a variable `idx`, and other changes like this.
3. You could also just do a line break in the middle of the line with `\`.